# How does the authd protocol work?

Tags: public-key, keys, authentication, key-exchange

So far, I have been able to research on what it is:

1. authentication;
2. authorization;

using resource [`authd`](http://www.theether.org/authd/).

I still have not come across a definitive answer or source which explains:

1. Why do we use `authd`?
2. When to use it?
3. How does `authd` work?

Can anybody help me answer these questions?

Comment: Never heard of it but it looks old and only supports RSA? At a quick glance, looks like the server challenges the client and the client signs it using their RSA key and the server verifies it. Alternatively the server RSA encrypts a challenge and the client must reveal it, or a representation of it I.e. a hash.

Comment: @cypherfox That's not what I read. The client simply receives a signed, time limited token from the server. There is only one RSA key pair: the one of the server. But it is probably an understatement to say that the protocol lacks a good online specification.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Ah looked at it from an ssh-client perspective. Agree with the lacking documentation.

Comment: It seems that there aren't many people here that know about the protocol. I suggest to try a [*nix QA site](https://unix.stackexchange.com) as well.